# TinyMCE + Wrapping code snippets

Tags: tinymce

Is there a tinymce plugin that wraps text within the  tag? Something similar to the formatting option from the WYSIWYG of SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on [this](http://www.codecall.net/component/content/article/44-programming/388.html) blog post. It adds a button to the toolbar and also wraps the selected content. Code formatting can be achieved by using [prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/)